# Ubuntu vim can't open a file

Tags: command-line, vim

When I try to open any file with `Vim` I get no error messages, but file is empty (*when I try to* `:q` *it says I should save before quit because of unsaved changes*) in `Vim`. Though I can see file contents using `tail` command

Here's sample output:

```
username@localhost:/home/username$ vim file.py
"indent" [New File]
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

*P.S. This happened to me when I moved my `.vimrc` to `.vimrc-old` in order to test new configuration, but when I changed to my back this is what happened.*

*P.S.S. I have tried reinstalled it/purged it, but no luck.*

Comment: Can you post the output of `echo $PATH` and `alias`?  Also if you run Vim without a vimrc by doing `vim -u NONE file.py` does the file open?

Comment: Without `.vimrc` works perfectly. `echo $PATH` = `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` which `alias` didn't print anything.

Comment: I did `echo $PATH` after I was at home (`cd ~`)

Comment: Ah so that narrows it down to something most likely in your vimrc.  Some other ideas: What was the exact command you used to move your vimrc, and can you post the contents of your vimrc?  To check if the vimrc is somehow corrupted, what is the output of `file ~/.vimrc`?

Comment: I used `mv` to move old `.vimrc` to `.vimrc-old`. Output from `file ~./vimrc` : `/home/username/.vimrc: ASCII text`

Comment: Oh, I actually removed `.vimrc` and it worked like a charm. Looks like my `.vimrc` was corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

Long story short: my `.vimrc` file was **corrupted**.

*Removing* it is a solution for my problem.